# How to know the public key type?

Tags: java, network-programming

I'm using the method `.getPublicKey()` which returns public key. http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/security/cert/Certificate.html#getPublicKey%28%29

How can I know whether the key type for the remote host certificate is DSA or RSA ?? I've tested this method in a reasonable amount of web sites. I always get Sun RSA public key and never DSA. I doubt that there is something missing I should do in order to get DSA key ? I know that RSA is much widely used than DSA, but I suppose to see at least 1 DSA key in my set.

Answer (score 3):

Well, you could do `getPublicKey() instanceof DSAPublicKey`, probably?

Comment: I only have an object of type certificate. This object call the method getPublicKey() to get the public key. I'm not sure if I understand you correctly, but as I said, the only object I have is the certificate. The question is : How can I know if the Public key for this certificate is RSA or DSA ?

Comment: @JuryA I suggest you read this answer again properly. Everything you have just asked is already answered.

Comment: @Jury, louis is saying that `getPublickey` returns a `PublicKey` and `DSAPublicKey` is an implementation. http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/security/PublicKey.html

Comment: You can also call `getAlgorithm()` on the key instance instead of using `instanceof`.